# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

hoy quiero generar mi APK y al tratar de hacerlo me encuentro con este error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Este error no me permite avanzar, Cuando emulo mi proyecto se ejecuta en el emulador sin problema, luego le hice un Clean project y parecía que iba bien, este error también me aparece cuando de doy Rebuild Project, estoy tratando tratando de generar el APK mediante Build > Build APKs. A continuación muestro mi archivo build.gradle, agradezco su ayuda.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tecnologias.uniagustapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })

compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intenta con agregar en tu `Gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

¿ Que es esto ?

> Las aplicaciones de Android de forma predeterminada tienen
>   compatibilidad con SingleDex, lo que limita su aplicación para tener
>   solo 65536 métodos (referencias). Entonces multidexEnabled = true
>   simplemente significa que ahora puede escribir más de 65536 métodos
>   (referencias) en su aplicación.

Mas información [aquí](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=es) por si te interesa entender mas.